# How set a standard format specifier to be used throughout a module when using f-strings?

Tags: python-3.x, format, f-string

I am using f-strings for formatting strings and injecting variable values into the string, is there a way to set a format-spec for an entire module in python?

I am aware of [Standard Format Specifiers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#standard-format-specifiers) which can be used to specify formats for each string, but how do I do it at once for the whole module?

Eg:

```
f""" Some random string {value1}, some more text {value2:.2f} ... """
```

Here I am specifying the format for `value2`, but I want to set a format for all globally.

```
f"""% profits are {profit}"""
```

Had I set format spec to `{profit:.2f}` this will be set to two decimal places, but I want to set that `:.2f` globally so that number decimal places can be changed with one variable update.

Something like `format-spec = ':.2f'` and all the f-string injected values should be displayed as floats with two decimals (if its a numbers).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, couldn't you just define the formatted string as a variable?  What am I missing?

Comment: @itprorh66 As a variable and specify it everywhere?

I want to avoid specifying it for each string... looking to set it once and use it through out the script.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to define a string format one time that is usable throughout a script.  I would create a function, callable from anywhere in your script that produces the formatted string as shown below:

```
def create_string(v_str: str, v_num: float) -> str:
    return f""" Some random string {v_str}, some more text {v_num:.2f} ... """
```

You can then use the create_string function from anywhere in your script and produce the desired output as illustrated below:

```
print(create_string('Some words here', 2.56))
```

which yields:

```
Some random string Some words here, some more text 2.56 ...
```

Comment: I am not looking for formatting the whole string.. apologies if my explanation wasn't more specific earlier..

Comment: I am looking for a way to specify `{:.2f}` somewhere so that I can use `f'Some text {var1} some text {var2}'` and both `var1` and `var2` here would follow `{:.2f}`.. hope that clarifies my question.

Comment: I could be proven wrong, but I don't believe there is any way what you want to do is possible, and furthermore I can't imagine a use case where it is necessary.

Comment: Use-case is simple, I want to define a precision and scale for all floats displayed in the module.

Comment: so create a function similar to my previous answer, that returns a formatted string for the float variable then embed the result in an output string of your choosing.

Comment: I only want to set the precision and scale not the format of the whole string! I am aware of a workaround that is to pass each float to a function (where its formatted) and then print, but I am trying to find a simpler way to define it at module level.